# Vb.net windows service and database query

Tags: sql, vb.net, windows-services

I am trying to create a windows service using vb.net to read sql table
every 3 hours and get all the new data created within the past 3 hours. I know how to create a windows service, but the challenge is how to get the newest data created within the past 3 hours from the database. Can someone help me with the query pls or help me with a Vb.net script to get the newest data each time. i am new to programming and any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Dee

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the creation date of your data in a column in the database. Then you can use a select statement something like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, ..., coln
FROM your_table
WHERE creation_date > DATEADD(hh, -3, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, How do i do this in vb.net assuming i dont have a creation_Date Column?

Comment: @Dee: If you don't have a creation date column then unfortunately you can't do it. If you have an auto-incrementing identity field, you could try to use that instead. You can remember the last inserted id each three hours and fetch all records with an id higher than that.

Comment: How do i write the code to remember the last inserted id each 3 hours and fetch all records with an id higher than that in vb.net?

Comment: Can anyboy pls tell me how i can query a database from vb.net and tell it to remember the last row, so next time i query i can tell it to get the data after the last row it remembered. I need to do this urgently.

Comment: @Dee: Try LINQ to SQL, with a timer.